# How schedule posts like in wordpress work, its a cron?

Tags: wordpress, cron, web-crawler, schedule

I mean, how for example article will be posted exactly in 16:00?
There is a cron that checking the schedule posts every minute?

I'm asking because i want to write crawler, that will bring content from specific website each time that this website will post a new content.

The same example we see in Google reader, each new article from your subscribed websites, reader will show right away

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

When a user visits the site (any user), a pseudo-cron job runs. Basically, every PHP page is hooked up to a cron-like environment that executes code when called.

I say "pseudo" because you can't distinguish it from a real one. The only way you can tell would be to browse the webpage to check for new content, triggering the job (which happens as you request the page).

As for the crawler, why do you need to crawl it? Just download the RSS feed (most themes support it). It contains all of the recent posts in a nice format.

Comment: Ok, so my question is - if i want to build a website that work on crawlers, and i want to visit my website once a month, i need to run server cron job which will run every X minutes/hours ? and not be dependent on users that visit my site

Comment: Crawlers request pages. Wordpress runs the "cron" jobs every time you request a webpage, regardless of the requester (be it a crawler or a browser). It makes no difference.

Comment: To clarify the difference: a unix cron job is guaranteed to run at its scheduled time, whereas a WP "pseudo" cron will only run if its triggered. In other words, if no one visits your site, the cron job will not run at all! Its also not guaranteed to run on time, and should not be used to run time critical cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

As @Blender noted, the events are triggered by a psuedo-cron process which runs when a user accesses the home page. It will execute scheduled actions as long as their scheduled time has passed.

You can hook your own behaviors into this process.  See [these pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aWP-Cron_Functions) on the WordPress Codex around WP-Cron, specifically [this one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) about scheduling events.